# Django ORM - Can I create a new object with a foreign key using a different column other than ID?

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm

I checked around a fair bit and could not find any examples of what I am looking for so i am not sure if it is possible at all.

I have a model with a foreign key. I want to create a new object in that model but i don't have the ID but I do have the field "username" value. I should also add that this is a foreign key relationship to another foreign key

WeekdayAssignment Model example:

```
class WeekdayAssignment(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    end_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    triage = models.ForeignKey(TeamMember, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="triagers")
    ...
```

TeamMember Model Example:

```
class TeamMember(models.Model):
    member = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Member Name')
    ...
```

User Model Example:

```
class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

What I would like to do is create a new object using the members username from the Foreign key's not the ID like this:

```
WeekdayAssignment.objects.create(start_date='2021-01-13', end_date='2021-01-20', triage__member__username='jac')
```

However, if i do this i get the error *WeekdayAssignment() got an unexpected keyword argument 'triage__member__username'* and same thing if i drop **__username**

If drop the **__member__username** from the field like this:

```
WeekdayAssignment.objects.create(start_date='2021-01-13', end_date='2021-01-20', triage='jac')
```

i get *ValueError: Cannot assign "'jac'": "WeekdayAssignment.triage" must be a "TeamMember" instance.* which is totally expected as it's not an ID or an instance.

So my question is, is there anyway i can use another field from the foreign key model to create the  data or am i stuck using the ID?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
jAC

Comment: It's possible to add any `TeamMember` instance directly in that field, but it has to be a `TeamMember` instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give instance of `TeamMember`. So, suppose a user with username 'Jac' logged in:

Below method is wrong:

```
wdass = WeekdayAssignment.objects.create(start_date='2021-01-13', end_date='2021-01-20', triage='Jac')
```

Below method is right:

```
t_member = TeamMember.objects.filter(member=request.user).first()
wdass = WeekdayAssignment.objects.create(start_date='2021-01-13', end_date='2021-01-20', triage=t_member.id)
```

Comment: this actually works better than what i ended up doing as per my comment below. I made a slight edit and changed it t-member to  TeamMember.objects.get(member=request.user). But this is what i was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. Under the hood Django's `create` queryset method uses `INSERT` SQL statement that creates a new row in the respective DB table. And a ForeignKey field corresponds to an integer DB column (usually) that holds a reference to a row in another table in your database. So in case of Django ORM you need to provide either a numeric ID or a model instance that represents your ForeignKey. If you don't have an ID but have another field value, then first you need to make another query by that field to find a model instance (a DB row) that has this value and use this model instance (or its row ID) in your `create` call.

Comment: Ahh makes total sense. Thank you so much! For anyone else that was looking for a way around this, i ended up doing a get on User, then used that result to do a get on the Member.